# Class-based decorators in Python - which PEP define syntax and semantic?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, pep

I open full list of PEPs: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/ and search by `decorator` keyword.

There are two PEPs with this keyword in title:

- [318: Decorators for Functions and Methods](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)
- [3129: Class Decorators](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/)

but they don't say anything about class-based decorators...

I wonder when and how class-based decorators introduced into Python.

**UPDATE** I talk about:

```
class NoArgsClassDecorator:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self):
        print('Inside %s.__call__(). You call %s()' % (self.__class__, self.f.__name__))
        self.f()
        print('Inside %s.__call__(). We finish %s()' % (self.__class__, self.f.__name__))

@NoArgsClassDecorator
def hello():
    print('hello')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "class-based decorators"? If you mean decorators on classes, that's the second one you linked. If you mean classes or class instances used as decorators, that's the natural consequence of allowing arbitrary callables as decorators. No one ever said it had to be a real function.

Comment: The decorator PEP talks about *callables*; classes are callable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I don't know about *callables*! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class-based decorators were included from the very start; quoting the [*Design Goals* section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#design-goals) of PEP 318:

> The new syntax should
>
> - work for arbitrary wrappers, **including user-defined callables**

Emphasis mine.

Classes are *user-defined callables.* Calling a class produces an instance; and like functions, class instances are *just another object*.

The fact that you can make instances callable too by defining a [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) on the class, letting you replace functions with instances, has long been part if the language and never needed to be called out in the PEP.